# Applying a .click() function for multiple HTML elements and changing context

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, this

I'm wondering if there is a way of instead of listing what happens when each individual element is clicked like:

```
$('#object1').click(function(){ stuff += object1amount };
$('#object2').click(function(){ stuff += object2amount };
$('#object3').click(function(){ stuff += object3amount };
$('#object4').click(function(){ stuff += object4amount };
$('#object5').click(function(){ stuff += object5amount };
```

I can have:

```
$('LIST OF HTML ELEMENTS').click(function(){ stuff += this.amount };
```

where 'this' is the context of whatever HTML element was clicked.

Comment: What's your HTML look like?

Answer (score 2):

This kind of selector is called as [**`Multiple selector`.**](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) And additionally you asked to maintain each html elements with different data, so at that situation you can use [**`.data()`**](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store memory leak less data with each html elements.

Try.

```
$('#object1,#object2,#object3,#object4,#object5').click(function(){
     stuff += $(this).data('amount');
};
```

To store data:

```
$('#sample').data( 'amount', 100 );
```

Answer (score 2):

If your element `amount` is stored inside `data` attribute like this:

```
data-amount = "....."
```

then you can use attributes [**starts with**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector to achieve your task:

```
$("[id^='object']").click(function() {
    stuff += $(this).attr('data-amount');
});
```

Comment: This looks like it would work perfectly. Apart I would be using this.amount instead of $(this).attr('data-amount'); since the various variables (object1.amount , object2.amount) are defined earlier. Would it be possible to do something similar but with 'If' statements?

Answer (score 1):

> Try this:

```
var _this = this;

$("[id^='object']").click(function(){ stuff += _this.amount };
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a class to the elements or a data attribute like `data-action=addAmount` and then just selecting off that. i.e.

```
$('.addAmount').click(...
```

or

```
$('[data-action=addAmount]').click(...
```

Answer (score 1):

add a class to your objects like class="stuff"

then you can use

```
$(".stuff").click(function()
{
stuff += this.amount;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `objects ids are input type of text`

```
var stuff = 0;
var objOnClick = function () {

    stuff += +this.value;
};
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    document.getElementById('object' + (i + 1)).onclick = objOnClick;
};
```